# visualise unconnected graph in Gephi

Tags: python, graphviz, gephi

I have a graphviz file generated in Python as follows:

```
strict graph G {
    iruo;
    valentin6232;
    shockwaver;
    jojo6938;
    beahero;
}
```

Unfortunately, if I open the graph file in Gephi it does not show any of the unconnected nodes. If I connect at least one edge it shows only the nodes of the connected edges. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled around a bit and saw that if you introduce an empty attribute, Gephi successfully show all nodes, unconnected or not.

```
strict graph G {
    iruo [];
    valentin6232 [];
    shockwaver [];
    jojo6938 [];
    beahero [];
}
```

However, the `dot` program is capable of handling nodes that don't have any attributes, so I guess this issue is something specific to Gephi.

Comment: If you have access to the python script it's a simple matter of just adding an empty attribute. An alternative could be to run the graphviz file through one of the graphviz programs, e.g. `dot`. Then attributes will be added to the nodes, but a layout will also be performed. However, I would recommend modifying the python script if possible since you eliminate an extra step compared to my other suggestion.